# How to break a while loop when break is supposed to be used in defining a function?

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

```
u=input('enter your sql password ')
import mysql.connector as s
mycon=s.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='{}'.format(u))
cursor=mycon.cursor()
cursor.execute('create database if not exists Reservation')
cursor.execute('use reservation')
cursor.execute("create table if not exists USER(user_id int primary key, first_name varchar(100), last_name varchar(100), aadhar_no varchar(50), gender varchar(10), age int, mobile_no varchar(50), email varchar(100), city varchar(100), state varchar(100), pincode varchar(50), password varchar(100))")
cursor.execute("create table if not exists TRAIN(train_no int primary key, train_name varchar(100), arrival_time time, departure_time time, availability_of_seats varchar(50), date date)")
cursor.execute("insert into TRAIN values(11019, 'Konark Express', '153000','154000','A','2020-04-10')")
cursor.execute("insert into TRAIN values(12025, 'Shatabdi Express','050000','055000','A','2020-04-10')")
cursor.execute("insert into TRAIN values(22881, 'Pune Express','114000','115000','A','2020-04-10')")
cursor.execute("insert into TRAIN values(10101, 'Mandovi Express','130000','133000','A','2020-04-10')")
cursor.execute("insert into TRAIN values(18520, 'LTT Express','071000','073000','A','2020-04-10')")
cursor.execute("create table if not exists STATION(station_no int, name varchar(100), hault int, arrival_time varchar(6), train_no int, primary key(station_no, train_no), constraint foreign key(train_no) references TRAIN(train_no))")
cursor.execute("insert into STATION values(1,'Kalyan',10,'140000',11019)")
cursor.execute("insert into STATION values(2,'Secunderabad',25,'142500',12025)")
cursor.execute("insert into STATION values(3,'Hyderabad',10,'210000',22881)")
cursor.execute("insert into STATION values(4,'Panvel',15,'132500',10101)")
cursor.execute("insert into STATION values(5,'Thane',10,'074000',18520)")
cursor.execute("create table if not exists STARTS(train_no int primary key , station_no int)")
cursor.execute("insert into STARTS values(11019,1)")
cursor.execute("insert into STARTS values(12025,2)")
cursor.execute("insert into STARTS values(22881,3)")
cursor.execute("insert into STARTS values(10101,4)")
cursor.execute("insert into STARTS values(18520,5)")
cursor.execute("create table if not exists REACHES(train_no int, station_no int, time time)")
cursor.execute("insert into REACHES values(11019,5,'140000')")
cursor.execute("insert into REACHES values(12025,3,'142500')")
cursor.execute("insert into REACHES values(22881,4,'210000')")
cursor.execute("insert into REACHES values(10101,2,'132500')")
cursor.execute("insert into REACHES values(18520,1,'074000')")
mycon.commit()
z=1
while True:
    import tkinter as t
    root=t.Tk()
    root.title('railway tickect booking system')
    e=t.Entry(root,width=35)
    e.grid(row=0,column=0)
    e.insert(0,'enter your user id')
    f=t.Entry(root,width=35)
    f.grid(row=1,column=0)
    f.insert(0,'enter your first name')
    g=t.Entry(root,width=35)
    g.grid(row=2,column=0)
    g.insert(0,'enter your last name')
    h=t.Entry(root,width=35)
    h.grid(row=3,column=0)
    h.insert(0,'enter your adhar card no. ')
    i=t.Entry(root,width=35)
    i.grid(row=4,column=0)
    i.insert(0,'gender')
    j=t.Entry(root,width=35)
    j.grid(row=5,column=0)
    j.insert(0,'age')
    k=t.Entry(root,width=35)
    k.grid(row=6,column=0)
    k.insert(0,'your mobile number')
    l=t.Entry(root,width=35)
    l.grid(row=7,column=0)
    l.insert(0,'email')
    m=t.Entry(root,width=35)
    m.grid(row=8,column=0)
    m.insert(0,'enter your city')
    n=t.Entry(root,width=35)
    n.grid(row=9,column=0)
    n.insert(0,'enter your state')
    o=t.Entry(root,width=35)
    o.grid(row=10,column=0)
    o.insert(0,'enter your pincode')
    p=t.Entry(root,width=35)
    p.grid(row=11,column=0)
    p.insert(0,'enter your password')
    t.Label(root,text='which train would you travel in?').grid(row=14,column=0)
    r=t.IntVar()
    t.Radiobutton(root,text='Konark Express-Kalyan to Thane',variable=r,value=11019).grid(row=15,column=0)
    t.Radiobutton(root,text='Shatabdi Express-Secunderabad to Hyderabad',variable=r,value=12025).grid(row=16,column=0)
    t.Radiobutton(root,text='Pune Express-Hyderabad to Panvel',variable=r,value=22881).grid(row=17,column=0)
    t.Radiobutton(root,text='Mandovi Express-Panvel to Secunderabad',variable=r,value=10101).grid(row=18,column=0)
    t.Radiobutton(root,text='LTT Express-Thane to Kalyan',variable=r,value=18520).grid(row=19,column=0)
    def click1():
        mycon=s.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='{}'.format(u),database='reservation')
        cursor=mycon.cursor()
        cursor.execute("create table if not exists TICKET(id int primary key default {}, user_id int, train_no int)".format(z))
        cursor.execute("insert into user values({},'{}','{}','{}','{}',{},'{}','{}','{}','{}','{}','{}')".format(int(e.get()),f.get(),g.get(),h.get(),i.get(),int(j.get()),k.get(),l.get(),m.get(),n.get(),o.get(),p.get()))
        cursor.execute("insert into TICKET(user_id,train_no) values({},{})".format(int(e.get()),r.get()))
        top=t.Toplevel()
        top.title('ticket preview')
        t.Label(top,text='userid').grid(row=0,column=0)
        t.Label(top,text='ticket id').grid(row=0,column=1)
        t.Label(top,text='first name').grid(row=0,column=2)
        t.Label(top,text='surname').grid(row=0,column=3)
        t.Label(top,text='train').grid(row=0,column=4)
        t.Label(top,text='arrival time').grid(row=0,column=5)
        t.Label(top,text='{}'.format(e.get())).grid(row=1,column=0)
        t.Label(top,text='{}'.format(z)).grid(row=1,column=1)
        t.Label(top,text='{}'.format(f.get())).grid(row=1,column=2)
        t.Label(top,text='{}'.format(g.get())).grid(row=1,column=3)
        cursor.execute("select train_name from TRAIN where train_no={}".format(r.get()))
        t.Label(top,text='{}'.format(cursor.fetchone())).grid(row=1,column=4)
        cursor.execute("select arrival_time from STATION where train_no={}".format(r.get()))
        t.Label(top,text='{}'.format(cursor.fetchone())).grid(row=1,column=5)
        mycon.commit()
    mybutton=t.Button(root,text='submit and proceed',command=click1)
    mybutton.grid(row=20,column=0)
    top=t.Toplevel()
    t.Label(top,text='would you like to enter more records?').grid(row=2,column=0)
    x=t.IntVar()
    t.Radiobutton(top,text='yes',variable=x,value=1).grid(row=3,column=0)
    t.Radiobutton(top,text='no',variable=x,value=0).grid(row=4,column=0)
    def click2():
        if x.get()==0:
            t.Label(top,text='close the windows').grid(row=6,column=0)
            break
        elif x.get()==1:
            t.Label(top,text='close all the windows to enter new record').grid(row=6,column=0)
    t.Button(top,text='submit',command=click2).grid(row=5,column=0)
    z+=1
    root.mainloop()
```

The program is showing error saying that the break statement is out of loop.
My main objective was to receive entries from user and add it to my sql database reservation.
so to add more records I created a while loop.
if the user wants to continue writing more records the loop will go on or else it will break.
but I don't know how to proceed since its showing error.

Comment: You're using `break` in an `if` statement...there's no loop there to break.  Edit: Wait - sorry, is it wise to define functions in while loops?

Comment: how else should I do it then?

Comment: I'm not sure whether defining a function in while loop is good or not...I'm new to tkinter so as much as I know I need to make a function that can break a loop...so that the submit button would work...